# Jquery input form default value validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a small submit form on the sidebar of http://wines.effectwave.com/ I am trying to validate it with Jquery. I want to check if someone submits the form with the default values (eg. 'Full Name') then it should raise an error. So far I have validated it against empty values and minimum characters. But how do I check this condition of default values? Here is my Jquery code so far:

```
// JavaScript Document

$().ready(function() {

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#regform").validate({
        rules: {

            fname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },

            phone: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },

            comments: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
        },

        messages: {

            fname: {
                required: "Please enter your full name",
                minlength: "Your full name must consist of at least 3 characters"
            },

            phone: {
                required: "Please enter your phone number",
                minlength: "Your phone number must consist of at least 8 characters"
            },

            comments: {
                required: "Please provide some comments",
                minlength: "Your comments must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: As far as I know, `validate` is not a jquery function. So you are probably using a plugin. Which one?

Comment: He's obviously using jquery-validate: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Why are you using default values instead of placeholders?

Answer (score 1):

Could you consider using placeholder instead of value in HTML?

turn this:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="Full Name"...
```

into:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Full Name"...
```

It looks the same but the actual "value" is empty so you should be able to check if they are filled at all.

More info on placeholder at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom validation method and add it to jQuery Validator.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//add your custom method to validator
    $.validator.addMethod("DefaultCheck", function (value, element) {
        return value == "FullName" || "SomeOtherDefaultvalue"; // Default values to check against
    }, 'Please add a valid fullname');  //Validation Message

    $("#regform").validate({
        rules: {

            fname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                DefaultCheck: true   // your custom method
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use not equal. The J query docs are not clear about this...

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
 return this.optional(element) || value != $(param).val();
}, "The value can not be: " + value);
    $("#regform").validate({
            rules: {

                fname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3, 
                    notEqual:'Full Name'
                },

                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8
                },

                comments: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
            }
```

Comment: I didn't knew about `notEqual`, Do you have any documentation link ?

Comment: I don't sorry, like I said in the post, J query documentation is poor in this part. If the answer worked, please, up vote it :-)

Comment: **There's nothing wrong with the docs, because there is no such thing as `notEqual`** in [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com) or the [jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org).  This answer is pure fantasy and should be deleted.

Comment: no there isn't, but you can implement it. And the documentation does not show that easily. Something got Wrong with my code on the android app, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Since my last comment, you've edited your answer to create an arbitrary `notEqual` rule with the plugin's `.addMethod()` method. Based on the disconnected text of your answer and your last comment, I don't think you even realize what you're doing.  In other words, the `notEqual` rule is not documented at jQuery or jQuery Validate because it doesn't exist until you create it.

Comment: What I said is not well documented is that you can create custom validation methods. Anyways, sorry about the confusion.